# suse11 linux start jxbrowser error

Tags: jxbrowser

I've just installed JxBrowser library but I can't start the application.
I have this error on suse 11 spc3. The error message:

```
-- Product name: JxBrowser
-- Licensed version: 5.x
-- Licensed to: JxBrowser Demo
-- License type: Demo
-- License bound to product: License for JxBrowser Demo
-- Generation date: 2015-1-13
-- Expiration date: NEVER
-- License info: JxBrowser Demo License
-- Current date: 2016-10-18

JxBrowser license valid.

04:03:00 信息: OS name: Linux
04:03:00 信息: JRE version: 1.6.0_29 64-bit
04:03:00 信息: JxBrowser version: 5.3
04:03:00 信息: Starting IPC...
04:03:00 信息: Starting IPC Server...
04:03:00 信息: Starting IPC Process...
04:03:00 信息: Start Chromium process...
04:03:00 信息: The '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0' library exists: FALSE
04:03:00 信息: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.5.3/libudev.so.0' library exists: TRUE
04:03:00 信息: The '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: FALSE
04:03:00 信息: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.5.3/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: TRUE
04:03:00 信息: Command line: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.5.3/jxbrowser-chromium 1102 5827 --enable-npapi
04:03:00 信息: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.5.3/jxbrowser-chromium: symbol lookup error: //tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-43.0.2357.52.5.3/libjxbrowser-chromium-lib.so: undefined symbol: XISelectEvents
04:03:00 信息: Chromium process exit code 127;

com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: IPC process exited. Exit code: 127
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to JxBrowser [system requirements](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000013733-system-requirements) it doesn't support Suse 11 platform.